# Loading all Files in Directory / Loading Mongoose Schemas

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

Im trying to load my mongoose models with the minimum lines of code. So I decided to add a configuration variable

> models = 'models/**/*.js';

How can I now generate a function that goes through the given directory and loads all models?

Comment: you can directly add models by importing file like "require('/models/schema');"